# Stack around the variable is corrupted, visual studio 2010 issue

Tags: c++, memory, stack

I have created a simple function to convert decimal value to hexadecimal, it converts the small values and shows the out pout correctly but if I enter some big value, it give me the following error
**Stach around variable hexa is corrupted**

My function is

```
double convertToHexadecimal(int a,char b)
{
    int hexa[2]={0}, x,y,i=1;

    cout << "Enter the Decimal Number to convert to Hexadecimal: "<<endl;
    cin >> x;

    y=x;

    do
    {
        hexa[i] = y%16;
        y = y/16;
        i--;

    } while(y>0);

    for (i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        y = hexa[i];

        if (y==10)
            cout << 'A';
        else if (y==11)
            cout << 'B';
        else if (y==12)
            cout << 'C';
        else if (y==13)
            cout << 'D';
        else if (y==14)
            cout << 'E';
        else if (y==15)
            cout << 'F';
        else
            cout << y;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Comment: What happens when `i` gets to -1 in the while loop?

Comment: why would `i` get to -1? if it gets to -1, it should not enter into the loop,

Comment: @TaimoorAnwar Did you miss the "in the while" loop part?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz no, not really

Comment: @TaimoorAnwar The `i` variable (which starts at 1) in your loop has nothing to do with your `y` value.  They are not tied together.  Thus if `y` is a large number, `i` keeps getting decremented again, and again, and again, and again...etc. until `y` gets to 0.

Comment: @TaimoorAnwar I have a hard time believing you wrote this function given that your comments suggest that you have no idea what it does or how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

You error is in this part:

```
do
{
    hexa[i] = y%16;
    y = y/16;
    i--;

} while(y>0);
```

Since you have declared array of 2 element, you are restricting the length of the hexadecimal value to 2 (maximum number would be FF in hex or 255 in decimal). Hence for larger number, while `y>0` you would have `i<0`, causing undefined behavior.

Possible solution:

1. Increase the length of your array, or
2. Using string data type.

Using string would be a good option.

```
string hexa="";
int q;
while (y>0) {
    q = y%16;
    if (q == 10)
        hexa = 'A'+hexa;
    else if (q == 11)
        hexa = 'B'+hexa;
    else if (q == 12)
        hexa = 'C'+hexa;
    else if (q == 13)
        hexa = 'D'+hexa;
    else if (q == 14)
        hexa = 'E'+hexa;
    else if (q == 15)
        hexa = 'F'+hexa;
    else
        hexa = (q+'0')+hexa;
    y %= 16;
}
cout << hexa;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to throttle your loops to ensure that the index doesn't go out of bounds, instead of assuming that the index will always be what you expect:

```
 do
 {
     hexa[i] = y%16;
     y = y/16;
     i--;
 } while(y > 0 && i >= 0);
```

This will now not crash your program when larger numbers are inputted, however it will not process large numbers due to `hexa` being an array of only 2 `int` values.

Another solution for large numbers:

```
 #include <vector>
 std::vector<int> hexa;
//
 do
 {
     hexa.push_back(y%16);
     y = y/16;
 } while(y > 0);
```

You essentially now have the same array you were trying to implement, and there will be no buffer overrun here, since the vector grows when push_back() is called.  There also is no need for `i`.

Then the loop afterwards:

```
const char *hexValue = "0123456789ABCDEF";
for (size_t i=0; i < hexa.size(); ++i)
  cout << hexValue[hexa[i]];
```

No need for `if` statements.  Just do a table lookup for the character in the 
hex string literal.